# Launching app on iOS Simulator (waxsim no longer works)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've had a workflow for a while that ran automated tests by building an app for the simulator, then launching it using waxsim. On every new sdk release there were some small tweaks to keep it working. However, XCode 5.1 removed the iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient framework, so waxsim no longer works.
I tried using the ios simulator from the command line directly, as in:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /mydir/myapp.app/myapp
```

However myapp does not run, I just get the simulator loading the home screen. I can't figure out what might be going wrong, since I can't find a way to get any verbose output - the simulator does not complain about anything, it just doesn't load my app.

Any ideas, thoughts? Perhaps an alternative to waxsim that works on Xcode 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) was recently updated to support the new private framework DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient that is present in the current Xcode/SDK. I tried it and it seems to work fine, so I pretty much answered my main question.

Still, if someone has an idea why -SimulateApplication does not work (when the same app launches fine with ios-sim), I'd be curious to find out.